# Hide and show divs when user use back and forward buttons

Tags: html, jquery

Im working on PWA application. In my case I hide content div and show loading div when user click any link:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function() {
        $('.content').hide();
        $('.loading').show();
});
```

This works fine wneh user dont use back and forward buttons. If b&f buttons are used, there loading div is still shown anc content is hidden.
Im trying with

```
if (performance.getEntriesByType('navigation')[0].type == 'back_forward'){
    $('.content').show();
    $('.loading').hide();
}
```

But this works only in desktop browsers. On mobile doesnt.
How can I hide loading div and show content div when user enters page with b&f buttons?
Maybe I should disable b&f actions?

Comment: did you try to use an eventlistener on `DOMContentLoaded` (or `$(document).ready()`). It should be fired also on back and forth buttons and you should init the page state inside such handler

Comment: Yes, I put this into `$(document).ready()`, but doesnt work as I expect.
I use reload page on history traveling:

`window.addEventListener('pageshow', function (event) {
    var historyTraversal = event.persisted || (typeof window.performance != "undefined" && window.performance.navigation.type === 2);
    if (historyTraversal) {
        //alert('refresh');
        window.location.reload();
    }
});`